# Can't get GIF to align horizontally with bootstrap input inside input-group

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to align a spinner just to the right of the input box but it is going underneath:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" ng-model="searchTerm" ng-change="FetchNearby(searchTerm)">
        </div>
        <span><img alt="Logo" src="/Content/Images/ajax-loader.gif" /></span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/1e0v352r/

i've added a class to your span and moved it inside of the .input-group

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" ng-model="searchTerm" ng-change="FetchNearby(searchTerm)">
                <span class="logo_right"><img alt="Logo" src="/Content/Images/ajax-loader.gif" /></span>
        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

and added some css to position it

```
.logo_right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Comment: No luck with that, it places the text box to the left and the spinner to the very right of the screen. Is there a purely bootstrap solution? I tried using form-inline and pull-left with no succcess